# MySQL. How to get result of "GROUP BY" with distinct rows each in its own column?

Tags: mysql

The question is not exact. Here is what I mean.

I have this:

```
    f0 | f1 | f2
    ------------
    1  | 4  | a
    1  | 4  | b
    1  | 4  | c
    2  | 6  | d
    2  | 6  | e
    2  | 6  | f
```

I need this:

```
    f0 | f1 | f2_1 | f2_2 | f2_3 |
    ------------------------------
    1  | 4  |  a   | b    | c    |
    2  | 6  |  d   | e    | f    |
```

Comment: Without using a dynamic query construction then this would only be possible if you know the values of the rows that you want to split into columns in advance. In this case, this would involve knowing all the possible values of `f2` in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select t1.f0, t1.f1, t3.f2 as a, t2.f2 as b, t1.f2 as c
from t1 t1 
inner join t1 t2 on t1.f1 = t2.f1 and t1.f2 != t2.f2
inner join t1 t3 on t2.f1 = t3.f1 and t2.f2 != t3.f2 
and t1.f2 != t3.f2
group by t1.f0, t1.f1;
```

**[Example..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0eda6/27/0)**

Comment: +1 better than mine. I have missed "!=" is required.

Comment: Thank you. This is it. But... I need to test its speed. Database's size is about 20Gb.